# Foto de fondo que se mueve con mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

Quiero hacer un efecto como el que tiene este theme de Wordpress:

http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-frostwave/

En la sección donde hay como una galería de imágenes y dice cosas como "on the mountains", "take a flight", "a night to remember", etc.. cuando se hace hover con el mouse sobre cada imagen, hay un pequeño desplazamiento que resonde a como uno mueva el mouse.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este fragmento de código, es del sitio `codepen` del author:

[Krz Szzz](http://codepen.io/ccrch/) / [Zoom + pan the image on hover & mouse move](http://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/yyaraz)

He modificado el código: quitando el texto encima y que escalen todos en las mismas dimension.

```js
$('.tile')
    // acción del ratón
    .on('mouseover', function(){
      // escala la foto pasando por encima
      $(this).children('.photo').css({ 'transform': 'scale('+ $(this).attr('data-scale') +')' }); 
     })
    .on('mouseout', function(){
      // escala la foto a su tamaño original al salir de ella
      $(this).children('.photo').css({ 'transform': 'scale(1)' }); 
     })
    .on('mousemove', function(e){
      // aquí es donde se "mueve la foto"
      $(this).children('.photo').css({ 'transform-origin': 
                                       ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 +'%'});
    })
    // crear el los contenidos para cada foto
    .each(function(){
  
      $(this)      
        // añadir contenedor para las fotos
        .append('<div class="photo"></div>')      
        // crear imagen de fondo para cada contenedor
        .children('.photo').css({'background-image': 'url('+ $(this).attr('data-image') +')'});
});
```

```css
.tiles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .tile {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: transform .5s ease-out;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile" data-scale="1.2" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/"></div>
  <div class="tile" data-scale="1.2" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/"></div>
  <div class="tile" data-scale="1.2" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Lo hice y me funcionó, gracias.

http://brauli.cl/

Answer (score 0):

Hay una forma de hacerlo, mucho más simple y eficiente, y es usando las bondades del css

```css
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
}
.imgContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hoverEffect {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
.hoverEffect:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img class="hoverEffect" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmOcd.png">
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img class="hoverEffect" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF6aN.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img class="hoverEffect" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4kFg.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img class="hoverEffect" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDWHD.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img class="hoverEffect" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl4Fq.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pero no se mueve la imagen con el ratón, ese es el efecto que quiere saber el OP

Comment: Gracias por el dato, pero no es lo que estoy buscando. Lo que yo necesito no es que se agrande la foto, sino que se pueda mover con el mouse.